# VisualStudio extension develop：How to detect file is changed or How to detect file is dirty?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I develop vs extension, Now I need to know document is changed  or is dirty, then execute some operation.

Comment: You cannot get an event for this, you can only check the Document.Saved property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *specific* event you mention is [`ITextDocument.DirtyStateChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextdocument.dirtystatechanged.aspx), but I suspect this might not be the property or algorithm you actually want to use in your extension.

---

One way to do this (running code after the document changes) is using the [`BackgroundParser`](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin/blob/master/GitDiffMargin/Core/BackgroundParser.cs) class. Your overridden `ReParseImpl` method would be called some time after a change is made to the document (called the "reparse delay", with behavior very similar to Reactive Extensions' `Throttle` method).

Make sure to call `OnParseComplete` in your `ReParseImpl` method, like you see here:
[DiffUpdateBackgroundParser.cs#L106](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin/blob/4f22ac76b06ee30de563d2bbf79bd2c96d636021/GitDiffMargin/Core/DiffUpdateBackgroundParser.cs#L106)

The background parser is enabled by constructing an instance and requesting an initial parse:
[MarginCore.cs#L41-L49](https://github.com/laurentkempe/GitDiffMargin/blob/4f22ac76b06ee30de563d2bbf79bd2c96d636021/GitDiffMargin/Core/MarginCore.cs#L41-L49)